# Can I insert a document in sorted order?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, insert

I know I can find documents in sorted order, but can I insert them in sorted order? The data in the database is ordered like `set` datatype in Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Generally order of records/documents in most (all?) databases is undefined. If you want them returned in a specific order - specify the order when querying. MongoDB is not an exception.

You can't affect what physical location will the new document go to, but you can query by insertion order (see [$natural](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/)).